# How to enable Firebase in Flutter Web Applications? Where to find the html scripts of the Firbase products?

Tags: firebase, flutter, web, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

we're building a flutter app that uses some Firebase products. We've been struggling to find the scripts tags that must be added into the web/index.html file of a flutter project to use Firebase products.

To use firebase_auth for example, one should add :

`<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>`

But we cannot manage to find those scripts for all the other firebase products.
According to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0jFkP0A3B0&ab_channel=JohannesMilke) youtube video, it should be found at the bottom of the documentation of the products. So one should go to pub.dev, look for firebase_auth for example then click on "see the documentation" in the "Getting started section" and find it there. But the "(Web Only) Add the SDK" section seems to have disappeared in the documentation.

Could someone join a list of those scrips for all the Firebase products or give a link to a page where they can be found? More specifically we're looking for those products : firebase_auth, firebase_core, firebase_dynamic_links, firebase_storage, firebase_messaging and cloud_firestore. But it would be in everyone's interest to have a list containing the scripts of ALL the products.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to add scripts to your html file if you're using Flutter Web and Firebase...It works directly.

Answer (score 4):

The latest `FlutterFire` documentation says that you **no longer need to add these** to `index.html`. There is a [section in the docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation#web) that actually instructs to remove these from older projects.

But if you are interested I used these scripts **earlier** in a web-enabled Flutter project:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app-check.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

Comment: Alright I see thank you.